# What is the behaviour of operations on two pandas Series with non-unique labels?

Tags: python, pandas

The basic behaviour is that it tries to pair up values with the same label. If no label is found, it assigns `NaN`. If a label is non-unique on the left or on the right (but not both) it exhausts all possibilities. For example,

```
pd.Series((2,3), ("a","b")) * pd.Series((5,7), ("b","b"))
```

returns:

```
a     NaN
b    15.0
b    21.0
```

and

```
pd.Series((2,3), ("b","b")) * pd.Series((5,7), ("a","b"))
```

returns

```
a     NaN
b    14.0
b    21.0
```

But if the label is non-unique on the left and the right, for example

```
pd.Series((2,3), ("b","b")) * pd.Series((5,7), ("b","b"))
```

you get

```
b    10
b    21
```

I would rather expect it to exhaust all possibilities, i.e. to return

```
b    10
b    14
b    15
b    21
```

What is determining the subset of values it returns? Is it based on row order? If so, what is the rationale for that behaviour?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one interesting observation:

```
In [146]: a
Out[146]:
b    2
b    3
a    4
dtype: int64

In [147]: b
Out[147]:
a    2
b    5
b    7
dtype: int64
```

indexes:

```
In [148]: a.index
Out[148]: Index(['b', 'b', 'a'], dtype='object')

In [149]: b.index
Out[149]: Index(['a', 'b', 'b'], dtype='object')
```

Multiplication with different indexes:

```
In [150]: a * b
Out[150]:
a     8
b    10
b    14
b    15
b    21
dtype: int64
```

BUT if index is the same:

```
In [151]: a.sort_index() * b
Out[151]:
a     8
b    10
b    21
dtype: int64

In [155]: (a.sort_index().index == b.index).all()
Out[155]: True
```

---

[DataFrame.join()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) will join duplicates as you wish:

```
In [128]: a = pd.Series((2,3), ("b","b"))

In [129]: b = pd.Series((5,7), ("b","b"))

In [130]: a.to_frame('a').join(b.to_frame('b')).eval("a * b")
Out[130]:
b    10
b    14
b    15
b    21
dtype: int64
```